# Java weak references for closing connection

Tags: java, weak-references

I am trying to figure out the best way to close a connection to a service when my object is descoped.

I have something like this:

```
class something {
  public final LongConnection lc;
  public something ()  {
    lc = new LongConnection ();
    lc.initConnection ();
    new Thread (new Runnable () { 
      public void run () { 
        ReferenceQueue<LongConnection> rq = new ReferenceQueue<LongConnection> ();
        WeakReference<LongConnection> wr = new WeakReference<LongConnection> (lc, rq);

        // now it should start listening for the object to be added to the queue
        while (true) {
          Reference<? extends LongConnection> ref = rq.remove ();
          if (rq != null) { 
            rq.get ().shutdown ();
            break;
          }
        }
        // will fall through and die! 
      }
    }).start ()
  }
```

This way I can instantiate the something like this:

```
somefunction () { 
  something = new something ()
}
```

and when the method returns (and is descoped/gc'd) it will close the connection properly.

Questions: 
(1) Is this really AWFUL?!?! 
(2) Will it work (the testing is...in process..)? 
(3) What is the "right" way to shut down something? I don't want to promote the problem of shutdown to the next layer of the program if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes: in Java it is malpractice to couple the management of any resource to memory management. Everything but memory management must be done explicitly. Java 7 has introduced a helpful new construct called "Automatic Resource Management" that helps with the boilerplate involved.

Specifically, you don't get any guarantee as to:

1. when the JVM will realize the object is weakly reachable;
2. when the weak reference will be cleared;
3. when the JVM will notify you of that fact by enqueueing it into your reference queue.

Comment: Indeed - so that means don't do this? This connection isn't one that can be scoped to just a function or class. It is actually a shared resource that is encapsulated by the "something" class. Soooo don't do this?

Comment: Whatever problem you have, using weak refs is not going to solve it, but introduce yet another problem.

Comment: thats what i was afraid of :/

Comment: You need to introduce a mechanism that will be explicitly invoked at an appropriate point.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collection of a scarce resource, like a SQL `ResultSet`, `Statement`, `Connection` or file handle will *not* close the resource.  You should do that in a finally block in the scope of the method in which you acquired it.